# How can I read a value from a mongodb cursor inside the same publication where the cursor was generated

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor publication in which I was trying to use `.findOne()` to access the fields from the mongodb. But as I cannot return `.findOne()` from a meteor publish, I am now using just `.find()`. The problem is that it returns a cursor instead of a document so I am not able to read the values inside that cursor in my publish function.

Below is my mongodb query

```
var question =  Question.find({ "_id": quesId },
  { fields: {"pages": 1, "settings.name": 1, "status": 1 }},
  {limit: 1});
```

And I want to use the value of `pages` that I get from the above query inside the same publish function

Answer (score 0):

you can set an observer on your cursor and get a hook into the results. i do that frequently to transform the result.

e.g. (i am making the assumption that the publish name is "questions")

```
let cursor = Question.find({ "_id": quesId }, { "pages": 1, "settings.name": 1, "status": 1 }, {limit: 1});

let handle = cursor.observeChanges({
    added: (id, fields) => {
        // look at fields
        this.added('questions', id, fields);
    },
    changed: (id, fields) => {
        // look at fields
        this.changed('questions', id, fields);
    },
    removed: (id) => {
        this.removed('questions', id);
    }
});

this.ready();

this.onStop(() => {
    handle.stop();
});
```

this will give you a hook into the records that are added at the initial publish, and changed later. call ready() when your publication is ready to be published (you can see the this.ready() in the sample).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you want to access the single document in the cursor without doing a redundant `findOne()` in your code. You can transform the result into an array with `.fetch()` on the cursor, get the first entry with `[0]` and then directly get the `pages` attribute.

```
const question =  Question.find(quesId,
  { fields: { "pages": 1, "settings.name": 1, "status": 1 }});
const pages = question.fetch()[0].pages;
```

Note also that when searching on `_id` you don't have to specify `{_id: quesId}` in your filter, you can directly use the value you want to search on as the filter parameter, mongo assumes that you're searching on `_id`. Furthermore the `{limit: 1}` is redundant since you're searching on a scalar `_id` value and so you're guaranteed that the cursor length will be one.